# History of the Vedas

Tags: vedas, history

Could someone shed some light on the earliest we know when the Vedas were taught? Also at what point in time they were written down?

I'm aware they came from Brahman itself and were memorized and given from Guru to Disciple for a long time till at some point they were written down.